# Syntax error in SQL statement when selecting records

Tags: sql, excel, vba

i am trying to run the following statement in excel:

```
       Dim myquery As String
   myquery = "select * from batchinfo where " + "datapath='" + dpath + "' and analystname='" + aname + "' and reportname='" + rname + "' and batchstate='" + bstate + "'"

   rs.Open myquery, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

' deleting batchinfo and from other tables with rowid if duplicate exists

If Not rs.EOF Then
    RowId_batchinfo = rs.Fields("rowid")
    cn.Execute "delete from batchinfo where rowid=" + RowId_batchinfo
    cn.Execute "delete from calibration where rowid='" + RowId_batchinfo + "'"
    cn.Execute "delete from qvalues where rowid='" + RowId_batchinfo + "'"
End If


With rs
    .AddNew ' create a new record
    ' add values to each field in the record
    .Fields("datapath") = dpath
    .Fields("analysistime") = atime
    .Fields("reporttime") = rtime
    .Fields("lastcalib") = lcalib
    .Fields("analystname") = aname
    .Fields("reportname") = rname
    .Fields("batchstate") = bstate
    .Fields("instrument") = Instrument
    .Fields("macrowriter") = Environ$("computername")
    .Update ' stores the new record
    capture_id = .Fields(0)
End With
' get the last id

'MsgBox capture_id
rs.Close
```

but on the `rs.Open` line i am getting an error:

```
incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'
```

what am i doing wrong?

here is what the sql statement looks like:

```
"select * from batchinfo where datapath='F:\MassHunter\DATA\44612_PAIN\QuantResults\44612.batch.bin' and analystname='MLABS\nalidag' and reportname='MLABS\nalidag' and batchstate='Processed'"
```

Comment: Small point, and not the answer to your problem, but you don't need the first `+` concatenation in your assignment to `myquery`: `myquery = "select * from batchinfo where datapath='" + dpath + "' and analystname='" + aname + "' and reportname='" + rname + "' and batchstate='" + bstate + "'"`

Comment: In situations like this, I find it helpful to emit the dynamically built statement. Use something like a message box, print statement, etc to output the query and then paste it into a query tool. Helps to verify whether it's a bum statement vs parameter value vs a connection issue.

Comment: @bill thank you, ive pasted the statement: "select * from batchinfo where datapath='F:\MassHunter\DATA\44612_PAIN\QuantResults\44612.batch.bin' and analystname='MLABS\nalidag' and reportname='MLABS\nalidag' and batchstate='Processed'"

Comment: @billinkc when i pasted into query window it worked fine

Comment: maybe im opening it incorreclty rs.Open myquery, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Comment: Another small point: in VBA the concatenation operator is '&', not'+'.

Comment: @I__ I believe it is because you are working with strings, not numbers. For example Dim myNum As String: myNum = 2 & 2 yields "22" whereas myNum = 2 + 2 yields "4" (a string version of the number 4). So I assume VBA is doing the math and then re-casting the result as a String. Since the input values in your code are themselves Strings, it treats '+' like '&'. As a best practice I wouldn't recommend relying on this behavior, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your last option, `adCmdTable`, is incorrect. You probably want `adCmdText` instead.

`adCmdTable` is for when the passed text is just a table name.  Since you are giving a SQL statement, `adCmdText` is more appropriate.