# Incorrect Syntax Near the Keyword 'Select' Using VBA

Tags: sql, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [running sql statement from excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319441/running-sql-statement-from-excel-vba)

Here's the excerpt that's causing the issue:

```
   Dim myquery As String

   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   cn.Open ' Some connection that opens properly

   myquery = "select * from batchinfo where datapath='" + dpath + "' and analystname='" + aname + "' and reportname='" + rname + "' and batchstate='" + bstate + "'"

' dpath, aname, rname, and bstate are declared earlier in the sub 

   rs.Open myquery, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```

Here's a sample of the myquery string at runtime :

```
"select * from batchinfo where datapath='111119-0021_excel short summary_111122191339.xlsx' 
   and analystname='none' and reportname='none' and batchstate='none'"
```

However, on this line, the code breaks, giving an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'"

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Consider using the concatenation operator `&` rather than `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the recordset with the option `adCmdTable` which means that it will expect a table name not an SQL query.

Use the option `adCmdText` instead.

---

Also, don't use `select *`, specify the fields that you want returned from the query. That makes the code more robust.

Comment: That runs through now. Thanks!

I'll test out narrowing fields too for robustness!